# Prevent jQuery animation queue

Tags: jquery, animation, queue

I have found a number of answers for the same question in a DIFFERENT context.  I'm looking to add '.stop' to the following code to prevent animation queue buildup:

```
 //Top Mailing List Drop down animation
 $(document).ready(function() {

$('#top_mailing_hidden').hide();

 jQuery('#top_mailing')
   .bind("mouseenter",function(){
  $("#top_mailing_hidden").slideDown('slow');
 }).bind("mouseleave",function(){
  $("#top_mailing_hidden").slideUp('slow');
 });

});
```

Comment: ... and what's stopping you? What's the problem you're having with which you need help?

Comment: I'm just a n00b and have no idea how to plug into the above context... I tried the following and no luck

jQuery('#top_mailing')
   .bind("mouseenter",function(){
  $("#top_mailing_hidden").stop().slideDown('slow');

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just need to add it before you start the next animation

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var top_mailing_hidden = $('#top_mailing_hidden').hide();
$('#top_mailing').bind("mouseenter",function(){
    top_mailing_hidden.stop().slideDown('slow');
}).bind("mouseleave",function(){
    top_mailing_hidden.stop().slideUp('slow');
});

});
```

You might look in to the [hoverintent jQuery plugin](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html) though, helps with making things like this not so jerky.

Comment: I second the recommendation to use the hoverIntent plugin.

Comment: I ended up doing something totally different and using the hoverIntent plugin, but this is the answer!